# WYSIWYG mathEditor for simple html pages

Tags: html, math, xhtml, web

i want to know if there is some editor similar to Mathtype which can be added to simple html page. i have added TinyMCE to my page but i need a math editor or equation builder. all i can find are tools which are browser plugins or for MS Word. kindly suggest me tool which is purely a math editor.

Comment: Search (CTRL+F) "WYSIWYG" on this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_editor I'd recommend http://cnx.org/matheditor DEMO here: http://cnx.org/math-editor/popup

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this LaTeX equation editor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/about.php). It's not fully WYSIWYG but it has a nice GUI and LaTeX is hard to beat if it comes to nicely formatted equations. There is a Tiny MCE plugin available as well by the looks of it.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider looking at [jsMath](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/)
I've not really had time to try it in details but it might sort you out .. the samples look really good.